# Is it safe to store medicine/supplements in containers

Tags: supplement

I bought a box of supplement strips (Natberry plus) that consists 100 tablets. I feel it's inconvenient to store the tablets strip in my bag as it tablet comes out by accident sometimes. So i thought i can store all the tablets in a container.

Is it safe to store these tablets in an air tight container? Is it safe to take medicine/supplement out from the strip and store it in a container in general?

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE! Interesting question. Have you looked at the package insert what it says about storage? (Usually stuff like below 25 degree centigrade etc., but maybe they also instruct you to leave the pills within the strip).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question only the manufacturer or a pharmacist can answer.

Answer (score 4):

If they're stored in blister packs it may be that this is to control the humidity for the tablets which may be particularly hydroscopic.

> **PRODUCT INTEGRITY**
>
> This same protection improves product integrity and extends its shelf life. Consider that most consumers store their drugs in bathrooms where temperatures and humidity can be harmful to unprotected drugs. Unlike with the use of bottles, which are opened and closed by consumers multiple times, exposure to compromising elements occurs in blisters only when the protective barrier is broken and a single tablet or capsule is dispensed and administered.

You can of course cut the strips into tablet sized and store them in the bottle still blister wrapped.

https://www.ropack.com/2012/05/28/the-four-reasons-for-the-rise-in-blister-packaging/

Comment: Locally, just about all of them are in blisters. "May be" or    sources… would improve this answer,

Comment: It's an extra packaging cost for a health supplement suggesting it's actually necessary.

Comment: There is no pharmacist that I've seen on this site as of yet so I'm not sure we have anyone else able to answer that more definitively.

Comment: @DoctorWhom [Lucky](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/613/lucky) is, but it seems like they‘ve abandoned the stands. We used to have a firefighter, but she left too.

Comment: Upvoting now, as this is indeed logical and the safer way to go. But still, as just one example I can't go to a pharmacy here and buy an all familiar bottle of aspirin. All in blisters or individually sealed wraps. I am more than sure that it's a psychological/ marketing reason or whatnot for that.